# How does Ubuntu share its desktop?

Tags: 16.04, remote-desktop, sharing

I have shared my Ubuntu desktop:

[image]

What next? Should I use VNC or RDP client to access it or may be some other bicycle was invented for this?

**WOW**

I met another do-not-ask question :)

Comment: You can use Google's remote control or TeamViewer though

Comment: @sticsk sure, but what about Ubuntu's feature? Is this just several checkboxes for a beauty?

Comment: Belive me that I didn't even knew that Ubuntu has this feature until now

Comment: but i think you gotta set a password, give me some minutes to see

Comment: Note, that I asked, which client to use.

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/setup-ubuntu-remote-desktop-4129666 Most likely you need VNC

Comment: People probably downvoted your question beacuse this thing it was easy to find, if you find that article easy to use let me know